# Accessing different port pins using single name in embedded c

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I have 6 led's connected to **different ports** of a microcontroller. Say

LED0 -> P1.0

LED1 -> P1.3

LED2 -> P1.2

LED3 -> P2.0

LED4 -> P3.0

LED5 -> P4.1

Is there any way I can map the different addresses to a single name?

Lets say **LED_DATA = 0xFF** should assign **HIGH** to all the corresponding LED pins. Preferably it has to be done **without using a function** and also not like the below one

```
#define ( LED_DATA = a ) ( function(a) )
```

Is there any other way of doing this using struct, union, memory mapping or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do exactly what you want - assigning a single name to non-sequential memory areas without a mapping function.  I think the best you can do is minimize the time you spend in said function.

Depending on real-time requirements and your tolerance for carrying global state around, you could define a global variable, e.g. `unsigned char g_led_data;`, and assign the individual LED states e.g. using `g_led_data &= 0xef;` to indicate you want to turn off LED4.  Then from your main loop, you can call a function which writes the value from `g_led_data` to the hardware:

```
/* Call this from the main loop. */
void update_leds( void )
{
  P1.0 = ( g_led_data & 0x01 );
  P1.3 = ( g_led_data & 0x02 ) >> 1;
  ...
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it minimizes the amount of time you're spending in a function call to set the LED values - you only call the function once per iteration of the main loop, rather than every time your code sets the value of a particular LED.  The disadvantage is the aforementioned effect on real-time performance and now you have to carry a little bit more global state.

Comment: I would avoid global variables in nearly every case. It's the beginning of the end. Btw. You would spend much more time in the LED handler, when you call the LED's once per main loop interation

Comment: @jeb, I'm assuming that he would assign the LEDs continuously, even if they didn't change, e.g. if the health indicator LED should be off, I'm assuming he'll write a '0' to that bit every time he checks his status code(s), as opposed to only writing it on a state change, or if he's got an LED that's supposed to blink, he'll always calculate the current on/off state based on his tick counter and write that to the relevant bit.  I suppose it does depend on the application though.

Comment: You are right. It depends on the application, but we can only guess what the requirements are

Answer (score 4):

I recommend not to use macros or direct access.
It's better to write a function, it encapsulates the complete led handling.

```
void led_set(unsigned char ledNo, unsigned char mode)
{
  switch (ledNo)
  {
    case 0:
      P1.0 = mode;
      break;
    ...
  }
}

void led_set_mask(unsigned char bitmask)
{
  for (i=0; i< 8; i++)
  {
     led_set(i, bitmask & ( 1 << i) );
  }
}
```

Only in the case that you need really fast or often access to the LED pins, macros are better.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify; you seem to be wanting here to map multiple pins on separate ports to a single variable?

That can be done easily enough in C++ but not in C.  In C++ you would create a class that overloads the assignment operator, so that when a value is assigned, a function runs that extracts the bits and assigns them to the associated pins.  However even that is syntactic sugar, it still runs a function, it is merely syntactically identical to a normal assignment.